# How should data be passed into a directive when a scope is populated asyncronysly

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, coffeescript, angularjs-directive

I have a controller which populates some data asynchronously. That data is used by a directive.

Unfortunately, the directive does not display the data. If I remove the timeout (which is what simulates an asynch process), then things work fine.

I'm wondering what the best solution is. I'm quite certain this is a common scenario-- and that I'm going about things the wrong way. Is there a way to delay the directive from "loading" until the data in the scope is populated.

**HTML:**

```
html
  head
    link(
  href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css",rel="stylesheet",type="text/css")  
    title Hello World
  body(ng-app="app")
    .container

      .well.
        How should data be passed into a directive when a scope is populated asyncronysly

      div(ng-controller="StoogeCtrl")

       .panel.panel-default
          .panel-heading
            | All 
          .panel-body
            ul
              li(ng-repeat="stooge in stooges") {{stooge.name}}

        .panel.panel-default
          .panel-heading
            | Noe Moe
          .panel-body
            div(filter-stooge except="Moe" stooges="stooges")
```

**JavaScript(CoffeeScript):**

```
app = angular.module 'app', []

app.controller 'StoogeCtrl', ($scope, $q, $timeout)->
  stooges = [
    {name: "Moe"}
    {name: "Larry"}
    {name: "Curly"}
  ]

  getPromise = ()->
    dfd = $q.defer()
    dfd.resolve(bars)
    dfd.promise

  $timeout ()->
    $scope.stooges = stooges




app.directive 'filterStooge', ()->
  scope:
    stooges: '='
    except: '@'
  template: "<ul )><li ng-repeat='stooge in filtered'>{{stooge.name}}</li></ul>"
  link: (scope)->
    filtered = []
    for stooge in scope.stooges
      filtered.push stooge if stooge.name != scope.except
    scope.filtered = filtered
```

base on answer from ExpertSystem (below). I did this:

```
app = angular.module 'app', []

app.controller 'StoogeCtrl', ($scope, $q, $timeout)->
  stooges = [
    {name: "Moe"}
    {name: "Larry"}
    {name: "Curly"}
  ]

  getPromise = ()->
    dfd = $q.defer()
    dfd.resolve(bars)
    dfd.promise

  $timeout ()->
    $scope.stooges = stooges
    $scope.done = true
  ,
  3000




app.directive 'filterStooge', ()->
  scope:
    stooges: '='
    except: '@'
    done: '='
  template: "<ul><li ng-repeat='stooge in filtered'>{{stooge.name}}</li></ul>"
  link: (scope)->    
    scope.$watch 'done', (newVal, oldVal)->
      if newVal
        filtered = []
        for stooge in scope.stooges
          filtered.push stooge if stooge.name != scope.except
        scope.filtered = filtered
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is not shown, because you show the filtered data and at the time `filtered` is created there is no data in `$scope.stooges` (so you are sort-of filtering and empty array, which results in an empty array of course).

You have the following alternatives:

- `$watch` over `$scope.stooges` and re-build `filtered` once it changes.
- Use filtering in the view (which is probably a better practice). Either create your own filter (if you need advanced filtering capabilities) or use the built-in `filter` filter.

E.g.:

```
app.directive('filterStooge', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            stooges: '=',
            except:  '@'
        },
        template:
            '<ul>' +
            '    <li ng-repeat="stooge in stooges | filter:filterSpec">' +
            '        {{stooge.name}}' +
            '    </li>' +
            '</ul>',
        link: function filterStoogePostLink(scope, elem) {
            // If `except` is specified, exclude items by name.
            // If `except` is not specified, show all items.
            scope.filterSpec = scope.except ?
                {name: '!' + scope.except} : 
                '';
        }
    };
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/6WL5J/)**

---

<sub>BTW, you where `ngRepeat`ing the `<ul>` element (which would result in multiple `<ul>`s.

I assumed you wanted to `ngRepeat` the `<li>` element.</sub>

Comment: why does adding a filter get it to work-- how about if I didn't need a filter-- what approach would you take?

Comment: @ek_ny: I explain all that at the top of my answer. Basically, you this is wha happens: 1. `stooges` is empty 2. `filtered` is created from data in (the empty) `stooges` 3. `stooges` gets assigned to a new, non-empty array. At that point `stooges` contains the data, but `filtered` doesn't know anything about it (it was created based on the previous, empty version of `stooges`). _"why does adding a filter get it to work"_: The difference with the filter in the view is that Angular is smart enough to re-filter data when it changes.

Comment: _"how about if I didn't need a filter"_: Then you wouldn't use one I guess :) (just use `stooges` in the view). _"what approach would you take"_: I would take the approach in my answer (that's why I posted it as an answer). Near the top of my answer I also mention other alternatives.